# When I try to open the Default path, It's showing a blank white page instead of rendering both header and home components one after other

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Header from "./Header";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/">
            <div>
              <Header />
              <Home />
            </div>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I want to render both the Header and Home components one below other when I try to open the default path.

Answer (score 0):

```
in react router v6 react router Dom we have element prop available , there we can return the JSX with Home and Header component.

 '''
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Header from "./Header";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={(
              <>
                <Header />
                <Home />
              </>
            )
            }
          ></Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;

 '''
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass you component to element as a prop.

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Header from "./Header";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        { /* This header will show on each page if you want to show only on home page then add it to homepage and remove from here */ }
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          { /* <Route path="/about" element={<About />} /> */ }
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```